# Can't seem to find a way to push notifications using Azure Messaging

Tags: rest, azure, notifications, xamarin, push

I've been working on an iOS app for communications and I want it to be able to receive and send push notifications. I want to accomplish that by using the Azure Notification Hub service. I've been following [this (click here)](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/partner-xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-get-started/) tutorial up to the point where it says "Send notification from your back-end". After that I am a little bit lost:

· I cannot seem to install the NuGET package WindowsAzure.ServiceBus since it returns this error

> Adding WindowsAzure.ServiceBus... Attempting to resolve dependency
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager'. Adding
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 2.0.3' to Board. Could
>   not install package 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager
>   2.0.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoTouch,Version=v1.0', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

· I thought of using REST Sharp but I'm lost on how to use that library to connect to the Azure Notification Hub and push notifications

Please, any idea or comment would be greatly appreciated since I've been working on this for the last days and I cannot seem to find a simple solution. All I want to do is push a notification to the server so that all the other clients can receive it - for example, if an user posts an image I want all the other users to receive a notification.
I cannot seem to find a simple, straightforward answer to my problem.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue while installing the nuget packages in to xamarin application.
so i created a separate web api to push a message to all devices.